# How Can I input the value of a Visual c# track bar into a pen size value?

Tags: c#

How would I input a trackbar.Value into a value for a Pen? I am trying to take the value of trackBarSize and put in for an integer value, is this possible?

On line
`Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, trackBarSize.Value);`

I got this error:
`CS0236  C# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'WhiteBoard.trackBarSize'`

What would i have to do in order to get the value of the trackbar to be the value of the brush size?

If you want all of the values for each object, I can provide it.

```
namespace WhiteBoard
{
    public partial class WhiteBoard : Form
    {
        public WhiteBoard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Graphics myGraphics;

        bool mousePress;
        int xLast;
        int yLast;

        // Pens
        Pen BlaP = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        Pen ReP = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        Pen GreP = new Pen(Color.Green, 2);
        Pen BluP = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);

        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, trackBarSize.Value);

        private void WhiteBoard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myGraphics = pnlBoard.CreateGraphics();
        }

        private void pnlBoard_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pnlBoard_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                mousePress = true;
                xLast = e.X;
                yLast = e.Y;
            }
        }

        private void pnlBoard_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                myGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, xLast, yLast, e.X, e.Y);
                mousePress = false;
            }
        }

        private void pnlBoard_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mousePress)
            {
                myGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, xLast, yLast, e.X, e.Y);
                xLast = e.X;
                yLast = e.Y;
            }
        }

        // Lines

        private void btnLine1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myGraphics.DrawLine(BlaP, 10, 10, 590, 10);
            myGraphics.DrawLine(BlaP, 10, 10, 10, 590);
            myGraphics.DrawLine(BlaP, 10, 590, 590, 590);
            myGraphics.DrawLine(BlaP, 590, 10, 590, 590);
        }

        private void btnLine2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myGraphics.DrawLine(ReP, 10, 10, 590, 10);
            myGraphics.DrawLine(ReP, 10, 10, 10, 590);
            myGraphics.DrawLine(ReP, 10, 590, 590, 590);
            myGraphics.DrawLine(ReP, 590, 10, 590, 590);
        }

        private void btnLine3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myGraphics.DrawLine(GreP, 10, 10, 590, 10);
            myGraphics.DrawLine(GreP, 10, 10, 10, 590);
            myGraphics.DrawLine(GreP, 10, 590, 590, 590);
            myGraphics.DrawLine(GreP, 590, 10, 590, 590);
        }

        private void btnLine4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myGraphics.DrawLine(BluP, 10, 10, 590, 10);
            myGraphics.DrawLine(BluP, 10, 10, 10, 590);
            myGraphics.DrawLine(BluP, 10, 590, 590, 590);
            myGraphics.DrawLine(BluP, 590, 10, 590, 590);
        }

        private void WhiteBoard_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            myGraphics.Dispose();
            BlaP.Dispose();
            ReP.Dispose();
            GreP.Dispose();
            BluP.Dispose();
        }
        
        // Brushes

        private void rdoBlack_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myPen.Color = Color.Black;
        }

        private void rdoRed_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myPen.Color = Color.Red;
        }

        private void rdoGreen_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myPen.Color = Color.Green;
        }

        private void rdoBlue_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myPen.Color = Color.Blue;
        }

        private void rdoPurple_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myPen.Color = Color.Purple;
        }

        private void rdoYellow_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myPen.Color = Color.Yellow;
        }

        private void rdoOrange_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myPen.Color = Color.Orange;
        }

        private void rdoPink_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myPen.Color = Color.Pink;
        }

        private void trackBarSize_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtBrushSize.Text = trackBarSize.Value + "";
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myGraphics.Clear(pnlBoard.BackColor);
        }

        private void trackBarSize_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here are the values for all of the objects:

```
namespace WhiteBoard
{
    partial class WhiteBoard
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.pnlBoard = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.txtBrushSize = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.btnLine1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnLine2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnLine4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnLine3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnClear = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.pnlLines = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.trackBarSize = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
            this.lblBrushSize = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.rdoPink = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.rdoOrange = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.rdoYellow = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.rdoPurple = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.rdoBlue = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.rdoGreen = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.rdoRed = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.rdoBlack = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.trackBarColor = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.pnlLines.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBarSize)).BeginInit();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBarColor)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // pnlBoard
            // 
            this.pnlBoard.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.pnlBoard.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.pnlBoard.Name = "pnlBoard";
            this.pnlBoard.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(600, 600);
            this.pnlBoard.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pnlBoard.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pnlBoard_Paint);
            this.pnlBoard.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pnlBoard_MouseDown);
            this.pnlBoard.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pnlBoard_MouseMove);
            this.pnlBoard.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pnlBoard_MouseUp);
            // 
            // txtBrushSize
            // 
            this.txtBrushSize.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.txtBrushSize.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(686, 184);
            this.txtBrushSize.Name = "txtBrushSize";
            this.txtBrushSize.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 22);
            this.txtBrushSize.TabIndex = 11;
            this.txtBrushSize.Text = "5";
            // 
            // btnLine1
            // 
            this.btnLine1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.btnLine1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnLine1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnLine1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 19);
            this.btnLine1.Name = "btnLine1";
            this.btnLine1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnLine1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.btnLine1.Text = "Black Lines";
            this.btnLine1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.btnLine1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnLine1_Click);
            // 
            // btnLine2
            // 
            this.btnLine2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.btnLine2.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnLine2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnLine2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(82, 19);
            this.btnLine2.Name = "btnLine2";
            this.btnLine2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnLine2.TabIndex = 2;
            this.btnLine2.Text = "Red Lines";
            this.btnLine2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.btnLine2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnLine2_Click);
            // 
            // btnLine4
            // 
            this.btnLine4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.btnLine4.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnLine4.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnLine4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(82, 48);
            this.btnLine4.Name = "btnLine4";
            this.btnLine4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnLine4.TabIndex = 4;
            this.btnLine4.Text = "Blue Lines";
            this.btnLine4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.btnLine4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnLine4_Click);
            // 
            // btnLine3
            // 
            this.btnLine3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.btnLine3.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnLine3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnLine3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 48);
            this.btnLine3.Name = "btnLine3";
            this.btnLine3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnLine3.TabIndex = 3;
            this.btnLine3.Text = "Green Lines";
            this.btnLine3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.btnLine3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnLine3_Click);
            // 
            // btnClear
            // 
            this.btnClear.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Tomato;
            this.btnClear.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Firebrick;
            this.btnClear.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 2;
            this.btnClear.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnClear.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnClear.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.btnClear.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(618, 578);
            this.btnClear.Name = "btnClear";
            this.btnClear.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(156, 34);
            this.btnClear.TabIndex = 5;
            this.btnClear.Text = "Clear Board";
            this.btnClear.UseMnemonic = false;
            this.btnClear.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.btnClear.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnClear_Click);
            // 
            // pnlLines
            // 
            this.pnlLines.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonShadow;
            this.pnlLines.Controls.Add(this.btnLine3);
            this.pnlLines.Controls.Add(this.btnLine1);
            this.pnlLines.Controls.Add(this.btnLine4);
            this.pnlLines.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.pnlLines.Controls.Add(this.btnLine2);
            this.pnlLines.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(618, 12);
            this.pnlLines.Name = "pnlLines";
            this.pnlLines.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(161, 75);
            this.pnlLines.TabIndex = 8;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 0);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 16);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "Lines";
            // 
            // trackBarSize
            // 
            this.trackBarSize.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonShadow;
            this.trackBarSize.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.trackBarSize.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(618, 135);
            this.trackBarSize.Name = "trackBarSize";
            this.trackBarSize.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(161, 45);
            this.trackBarSize.TabIndex = 9;
            this.trackBarSize.TabStop = false;
            this.trackBarSize.TickStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TickStyle.Both;
            this.trackBarSize.Value = 5;
            this.trackBarSize.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.trackBarSize_ValueChanged);
            this.trackBarSize.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.trackBarSize_MouseUp);
            // 
            // lblBrushSize
            // 
            this.lblBrushSize.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblBrushSize.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.lblBrushSize.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.lblBrushSize.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(658, 120);
            this.lblBrushSize.Name = "lblBrushSize";
            this.lblBrushSize.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(81, 16);
            this.lblBrushSize.TabIndex = 10;
            this.lblBrushSize.Text = "Brush Size";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.AutoSize = true;
            this.label3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.label3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 0);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 16);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label3.Text = "Brush Colors";
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonShadow;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.rdoPink);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.rdoOrange);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.rdoYellow);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.rdoPurple);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.rdoBlue);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.rdoGreen);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.rdoRed);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.rdoBlack);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label3);
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(618, 212);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(161, 116);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 10;
            // 
            // rdoPink
            // 
            this.rdoPink.AutoSize = true;
            this.rdoPink.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.rdoPink.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(91, 90);
            this.rdoPink.Name = "rdoPink";
            this.rdoPink.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 17);
            this.rdoPink.TabIndex = 8;
            this.rdoPink.Text = "Pink";
            this.rdoPink.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.rdoPink.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rdoPink_CheckedChanged);
            // 
            // rdoOrange
            // 
            this.rdoOrange.AutoSize = true;
            this.rdoOrange.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.rdoOrange.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 90);
            this.rdoOrange.Name = "rdoOrange";
            this.rdoOrange.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 17);
            this.rdoOrange.TabIndex = 7;
            this.rdoOrange.Text = "Orange";
            this.rdoOrange.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.rdoOrange.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rdoOrange_CheckedChanged);
            // 
            // rdoYellow
            // 
            this.rdoYellow.AutoSize = true;
            this.rdoYellow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.rdoYellow.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(91, 66);
            this.rdoYellow.Name = "rdoYellow";
            this.rdoYellow.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(56, 17);
            this.rdoYellow.TabIndex = 6;
            this.rdoYellow.Text = "Yellow";
            this.rdoYellow.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.rdoYellow.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rdoYellow_CheckedChanged);
            // 
            // rdoPurple
            // 
            this.rdoPurple.AutoSize = true;
            this.rdoPurple.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.rdoPurple.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 66);
            this.rdoPurple.Name = "rdoPurple";
            this.rdoPurple.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 17);
            this.rdoPurple.TabIndex = 5;
            this.rdoPurple.Text = "Purple";
            this.rdoPurple.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.rdoPurple.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rdoPurple_CheckedChanged);
            // 
            // rdoBlue
            // 
            this.rdoBlue.AutoSize = true;
            this.rdoBlue.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.rdoBlue.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(91, 43);
            this.rdoBlue.Name = "rdoBlue";
            this.rdoBlue.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 17);
            this.rdoBlue.TabIndex = 4;
            this.rdoBlue.Text = "Blue";
            this.rdoBlue.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.rdoBlue.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rdoBlue_CheckedChanged);
            // 
            // rdoGreen
            // 
            this.rdoGreen.AutoSize = true;
            this.rdoGreen.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.rdoGreen.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 42);
            this.rdoGreen.Name = "rdoGreen";
            this.rdoGreen.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(54, 17);
            this.rdoGreen.TabIndex = 3;
            this.rdoGreen.Text = "Green";
            this.rdoGreen.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.rdoGreen.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rdoGreen_CheckedChanged);
            // 
            // rdoRed
            // 
            this.rdoRed.AutoSize = true;
            this.rdoRed.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.rdoRed.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(91, 19);
            this.rdoRed.Name = "rdoRed";
            this.rdoRed.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 17);
            this.rdoRed.TabIndex = 2;
            this.rdoRed.Text = "Red";
            this.rdoRed.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.rdoRed.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rdoRed_CheckedChanged);
            // 
            // rdoBlack
            // 
            this.rdoBlack.AutoSize = true;
            this.rdoBlack.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.rdoBlack.Checked = true;
            this.rdoBlack.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 19);
            this.rdoBlack.Name = "rdoBlack";
            this.rdoBlack.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(52, 17);
            this.rdoBlack.TabIndex = 1;
            this.rdoBlack.TabStop = true;
            this.rdoBlack.Text = "Black";
            this.rdoBlack.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.rdoBlack.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rdoBlack_CheckedChanged);
            // 
            // trackBarColor
            // 
            this.trackBarColor.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonShadow;
            this.trackBarColor.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.trackBarColor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(618, 527);
            this.trackBarColor.Maximum = 255;
            this.trackBarColor.Name = "trackBarColor";
            this.trackBarColor.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(161, 45);
            this.trackBarColor.TabIndex = 12;
            this.trackBarColor.TabStop = false;
            this.trackBarColor.TickStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TickStyle.Both;
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(658, 508);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(91, 16);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 13;
            this.label2.Text = "Board Color";
            // 
            // WhiteBoard
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveBorder;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(787, 624);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.trackBarColor);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtBrushSize);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblBrushSize);
            this.Controls.Add(this.trackBarSize);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pnlLines);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnClear);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pnlBoard);
            this.Name = "WhiteBoard";
            this.Text = "White Board";
            this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.WhiteBoard_FormClosing);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.WhiteBoard_Load);
            this.pnlLines.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.pnlLines.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBarSize)).EndInit();
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel1.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBarColor)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel pnlBoard;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnLine1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnLine2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnLine4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnLine3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnClear;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel pnlLines;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trackBarSize;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblBrushSize;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtBrushSize;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rdoPink;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rdoOrange;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rdoYellow;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rdoPurple;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rdoBlue;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rdoGreen;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rdoRed;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rdoBlack;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trackBarColor;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not drawing by handling the `.Paint()` event? Usually the event handler provides the `Graphics` object, and you don't need to `.CreateGraphics()`. Anyway [edit] your post and provide valid code. You have statements inside a class declaration that are not part of a method.

Comment: Where in your code does the error trigger? Where do you set the value of the track bar? Your code is _very_ incomplete and the problem could not be reproduced in order to be answered effectively.

Comment: I am extremely new to c# and coding in general, you help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this declaration line:

```
Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, trackBarSize.Value);
```

You can't use `trackBarSize.Value` because the control hasn't even been created and initialized yet.

So simply pick a default size and use that:

```
Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
```

Then, in the `ValueChanged()` event of your TrackBar, you'd update the `Width` property of your Pen:

```
private void trackBarSize_ValueChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    myPen.Width = (Single)trackBarSize.Value;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this fixed it exactly! Thank you!!